# Using OwlBot Dictionary API CORSPolicy issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

I'm trying to retrieve data from this OwlBot API (documentation can be found here https://owlbot.info/?ref=public-apis) but the console keeps returning me the error: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

```
    function getWord(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://owlbot.info/api/v4/dictionary/owl?format=json' , 

            headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", 
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : 'true', 
                        "Authorization": "Token" + "<my token>"  
                        }, //Authentication using a token to access API

            type: "GET",


            data: { //parameters 
            },

        })

            .done(function (data) {
                // Show formatted JSON on webpage.
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

            })

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way is you can use javascript fetch async function for calling an API

```
let url = 'https://owlbot.info/api/v4/dictionary/hello';

let params = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Token ' + 'pasteYourTokenHere'
    }
}
fetch(url, params)
    .then((res) => res.json()
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result)
        }))
```